# How to check if something is a file or a directory within an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, directory

I am trying to filter out some folders in this array:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 20151113_152308.jpg
    [3] => 20160524_173033.jpg
    [4] => 20160810_100405.jpg
    [5] => 20160816_142932.jpg
    [6] => 20160817_135507.jpg
    [7] => 20170203_145901.jpg
    [8] => 20170203_151235.jpg
    [9] => Afbeelding-ifone-131.jpg
    [10] => Afbeelding-ifone-508.jpg
    [11] => Bestratingswerkzaamheden
    [12] => Mvc-161.jpg
    [13] => Rioleringswerkzaamheden
    [14] => SANY0016.jpg
    [15] => SANY0036.jpg
    [16] => SANY0060.jpg
    [17] => SANY0132.jpg
    [18] => SANY0133.jpg
    [19] => SANY0158.jpg
    [20] => SANY0159.jpg
    [21] => SANY0361.jpg
    [22] => Zeefwerkzaamheden
)
```

As you can see there are files in the array but also some folders (no extension). I've tried filtering them out using `is_dir()`.

Using the following code:

```
<?PHP
//Base path
$pad = "/home/studione/public_html/_extern/website/cms/images/beeldbank/".$alias."";
//Get everything from above path
$directories = array_diff(scandir($pad), array('.', '..', 'index.html'));
// Print array of above
echo '<pre>';
print_r($directories);
echo '</pre>';

foreach($directories as $image){

  if(!is_dir($image){
      $impressieslider .= '
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="impressiegallerij" href="cms/images/beeldbank/'.$alias.'/'.$image.'">
          '.$directory.'
          <img src="cms/images/beeldbank/'.$alias.'/'.$image.'" class="d-block img-fluid gallerypageimg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>';
  }
}
echo impressieslider;
?>
```

But I still see folders on my page, why? I also tried echoing a string inside the loop whenever the array reaches a folder but I don't see anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _“But I still see folders on my page, why?”_ - because you neglected to take the file path into account at that point?

Comment: maybe: `if(!is_dir($image)` **)** `{`

Comment: From where you are getting value for '.$directory.'?

Comment: if(is_dir($pad.'/'.$image) == false) try running this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple function to check if something is a directory in PHP: The `is_dir()` function ( https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.is-dir.php ).

And here is a simple solution:

```
$path = ''; // must be the path to the directory you want to check

$files_only = array_filter($directories, function($file_or_directory) use ($path) {
  // make sure you have the correct full path here with the realpath() function
  if(!is_dir(realpath($path . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . $file_or_directory))) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Not that if you just want the filter through the naming this is not possible as there are files without extensions and directory names with points in it. You can not be sure if only the correct things are filtered out if you can not access this directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can do in your case. (But this is not a perfect solution, And it won't work if your directory contains (.) character)

```
foreach($directories as $image){
   $is_file = explode('.', $image);
  if(count($is_file) > 1 ) { //you can check either this file exist or not.
      $impressieslider .= '
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="impressiegallerij" href="cms/images/beeldbank/'.$alias.'/'.$image.'">
          '.$directory.'
          <img src="cms/images/beeldbank/'.$alias.'/'.$image.'" class="d-block img-fluid gallerypageimg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>';
  }
}
echo impressieslider;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way

```
$dirPath = 'path/to/images/';
foreach(glob($dirPath.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}',GLOB_BRACE) as $file){
   $imgs[] =  basename($file);
}
```